# Translating term from french in Probability

Tags: translation-request

I am reading through J-C.Laleuf's *Processus et intégrales stochastiques, Ellipses 2014*. I need to know wether I'm correct in the translation of this phrase :

On dit qu'un **noyau markovien** $P_x(x,B)$ est **une loi conditionnée de $Y$ par $X$** si et seulement si.

=> We say that a **markovian kernel** $P_x(x,B)$ is a **conditioned distribution of $Y$ by $X$** if and only if

The term ($Y$ par $X$) can be translated to ($Y$ by $X$ or $Y$ given $X$), so I'm stuck.

Comment: It is $Y$ given $X$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks !